# View animated GIFs playing in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, gif, animated-gif

I have a python project where I create a set of plots and create a `.GIF` file by joining them. However, when I try to see the animated GIF in my IDE, It just shows the first frame instead of the whole 10 frames of the animation.

Is there a plugin I could install in Pycharm that allows it to show GIF files as animations?

Comment: I know a workaround to watch GIFs: navigate to *Preferences | Editor | File Types*, find HTML and associate *.gif* pattern with it. After that, right-click on the file in Project View and select *Open in | Browser | IDEA Preview*.

Comment: @s0xzwasd This worked, Thanks. You can write it as an answer; Seems to be the only way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following steps and display your GIFs in the built-in PyCharm browser:

- Navigate to *Preferences/Settings | Editor | File Types*.
- Find HTML and associate the `*.gif` pattern with it.
- Select a gif in the *Project View* (*View | Tool Windows | Project*), right-click on it and select *Open In | Browser | PyCharm Preview*.